# Risk site on ubuntu, What to do?

Tags: security

I accidentally enter to gmai.com trying to enter to gmail. I saw a moving image that seems to be loading and immediately I closed firefox. Do you know if that site is safe? And in case it's not.I What should I do? I use that PC for working, because of that I fear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These instructions are for firefox.

**First**, click on the hamburger menu.

**Next**, click on the blue question mark help icon at the bottom of the dropdown.

**Then**, click on "report deceptive site".

This will take you to the report web forgery page where you can submit a complaint.

Also, you can check to see if a website is safe by searching the URL at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/). A quick search of this URL shows this is a malicious, phishing, malware website.

Additionally, [looking at the IP](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/ip-address/216.157.88.26/relations), under "communicating files" it only shows Windows and Android files but there is one MS Word document listed. The two Android files appear to be apk files. According to what we know about the website, it does not appear to be a threat to you on Ubuntu. However, it is a threat as a phishing website if you were to enter your login credentials to the website.